# TSQL Determine if parameter is structured type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using this procedure to determine type of parameters of stored procedure.

```
select  
    'Parameter_name' = name,  
    'Type' = type_name(user_type_id),  
    'Length' = max_length,  
    'Prec' = case 
                when type_name(system_type_id) = 'uniqueidentifier' 
                   then precision  
                else OdbcPrec(system_type_id, max_length, precision) 
             end,  
    'Scale' = OdbcScale(system_type_id, scale),  
    'Param_order' = parameter_id,  
    'Collation' = convert(sysname, 
                case when system_type_id in (35, 99, 167, 175, 231, 239)  
                then ServerProperty('collation') end)  
from 
    sys.parameters 
where 
    object_id = object_id('MySchema.MyProcedure')
```

But if parameter is table value then I am getting the name of type.

How can I determine if it's a 'structured' type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you query `sys.table_types` or `sys.types` you can see all table types in your database:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.table_types;

SELECT *
FROM sys.types
WHERE is_table_type = 1;
```

You can see that the `system_type_id` is the same for all table types. You can extract it and use in your query. Alternative way is to store the above information in a table variable or temporary table and join it (LEFT JOIN) to the `sys.parameters`.